# How Long Are Moderator Terms?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Does anyone know how often elections are held; how often moderators are re-elected?

Comment: Lev, did you withdraw your nomination because of this answer? I think SE has not really decided about this yet (they haven't faced a serious problem about it and therefore don't have a policy on it). It seems that on SO they had a recent election to add a number of new moderators as the SO community grow and of course you can stop being a moderator when you decide. I hope that you withdraw your withdrawal and continue to run to be a moderator.

Comment: Yes (good eye!) -- an indefinite term worries me, especially because without fixed elections set in advance it is unclear what the expectation will be.  I imagined a moderator working hard for say 6 months and then letting someone else do it... without upsetting the expectations/ideas of the community and of other moderators.  I withdrew so that I would reconsider my nomination in light of this answer because it was very much different from what I thought the policy is (and should be).

Comment: ps. Thank you for your encouragement. Actually seeing good and enthusiastic candidates such as yourself makes me feel less of a need to run!

Comment: @Lev, the hope is that we can keep adding more moderators as time goes on, so that the work gets amortized down. There are so many of us who do moderator-like jobs anyway !

Comment: After some thought, I have re-nominated myself.  But my text is faded.  Fair punishment I guess :)

Comment: @Lev: I posted a [bug report](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/907/nomination-statement-is-grayed-out-after-re-nomination) on meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to renominate myself because of a mystery policy nobody knew about. http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/907/nomination-statement-is-grayed-out-after-re-nomination/908#908

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See discussion at

[Should Community Moderators be "elected for life", or have terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms)

but the consensus was effectively for life, or until they get dragged away by other concerns -- guess which is more common in practice? :)